# Convert a MSSQL String to Hex and unhex the value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to convert a string in Microsoft SQL to hexdecimal value, for example this:

```
declare @b varbinary(max)
set @b = (Select cast('Ali' as varbinary))

select cast(@b as varchar(max))
select @b
```

It returns:

[image]

This is great! But know I want to unhex the exact string in MySQL:

[image]

So in MySQL the string looks a bit different from the string I get from MSSQL. Maybe I could do a string replace or something

**But with a more complex string it even varys between mssql and mysql:**

-- Same procedure as before, just tried another string: --

[image]

[image]

```
MSSQL-String: 0x53414D31302F32303130E4F6FCDF5C2A23E92D656E64657C3C6469762073
MySQL-String:   53414D31302F32303130C3A4C3B6C3BCC39F2A23C3A92D656E
```

The beginning is the same (maybe because of the SAM), but it seems to be a problem with the special chars ... :-(

Answer (score 7):

The SQL Server and MySQL hex encodings start to diverge at position 11.  The character at that position is `ä`, the first non-ascii character .  So there is probable cause to believe that each database uses a different encoding.

**The MySQL encoding is UTF-8**

The encoding of `ä` in UTF-8 is `0xC3A4`, so that's what MySQL uses.  This is confirmed by the [utf-8 decoder](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder):

```
53414D31302F32303130C3A4C3B6C3BCC39F2A23C3A92D656E
-->
SAM10/2010äöüß*#é-en
```

The reason it is cut off is your MySQL client, which indicates the cut off with `...` at the end.

**The SQL Server encoding is Latin1_General (aka Windows-1252)**

The SQL Server encoding of `ä` is `0xE4`.  It's probably encoded in SQL Server's `Latin1_General` collation, which corresponds to [Windows-1252](http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/codepages.php?codepage=windows-1252).  The other characters `öüß` convert to `0xF6FCDF` under Windows-1252, confirming the guess.

To force SQL Server to use a different encoding, specify the `collate` clause:

```
cast('öüß' AS varchar(5)) collate French_CS_AS
```

The SQL Server hex string is cut off because of your `cast(... as varbinary)`.  When n is not specified with the CAST function, the [default length is 30](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder).  Try to specify the size explicitly, or set it to `max`:

```
cast('abcd' as varbinary(max))
                        ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

This query may solve the purpose:

```
Declare @b varbinary(max)
Select @b=Cast(CONVERT(varbinary(4), '0x' + @HexValue, 1) As varbinary)
```